# Git workflow to fork a local repository?

Tags: git, svn

What's the git equivalent of the following svn workflow:

1. `export foo`
2. `import bar`

Is it the following?

1. `checkout master`
2. `tag foo`
3. `branch bar`

Comment: What do you guys think about simply doing a cp -R on the dir, deleting the .git subdir, then git init-add-commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply creating a new repository with git init and then "git pull" the right branch from the other repository. You end up with a new repository containing only the one branch.